# How π = πP is equivalent to (I − P^T )π = 0 in stationary distribution of markov chain

Tags: matrices

How

pi=pi * P

where P is a probability transition matrix.
is equivalent to the equation

(I-transpose(P)) * pi = 0

where I is the Identity matrix.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall, $\pi$ is a row vector.

$$\pi = \pi P \Rightarrow \pi I = \pi P$$
$$I^T \pi^T = P^T \pi ^ T \Rightarrow (I^T - P^T) \pi^ T = 0$$

The last puzzle piece is $I^T = I$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @dEmigOd. One small clarification, Here P is a matrix if we bring a matrix from RHS to LHS doesn't it become inverse of P..?

Comment: If you do it by multiplication, then yes. But we here subtract vectors and change from row form to column.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response @dEmigOd.